# Checking if a variable is a double(float)

Tags: ruby

I have two variables which sometimes contain [double](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) data structure value. How can I determine in Ruby that a variable is having double value?

For example,

```
a = 3.4
a.is_a_double #=> true
a = "dadadad@asdasd.net"
a.is_a_double #=> false?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use any of following method to know this:

- [is_a?](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/is_a%3F)
- [kind_of?](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/kind_of%3F)
- [instance_of?](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Object/instance_of%3F)

See uses:

```
2.2.2 :009 > a = 4.5
 => 4.5
2.2.2 :010 > a.is_a? Float
 => true
2.2.2 :011 > a.kind_of? Float
 => true
2.2.2 :015 > a.instance_of? Float
 => true
```